# Python- How to keep X percent of data?

Tags: python, percentage, minimum

I have data that looks like this, let's say tab-delimited format:

```
Sample  Dog Cat Tarsier
A47 1   7   2
A48 3   3   4
A51 2   1   8
A53 0   0   0
A54 1   7   2
A57 0   0   10
```

Where although it may not be clear here, the sample names are in the 1st column, and the values correspond to Dog, cat or Tarsier.  I want to keep, let's say 90% of the data for each sample and delete the rest IN PYTHON.  For instance, for sample A47, I would want to retrieve something like this:

```
      Cat   Tarsier
A47    7       2
```

It is difficult for me because there are 3 pieces of information I need for each sample: Sample name, Animal, and quantity.
Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance

As per the comments below, the second row, could include all numbers but exclude all others that may be present (not shown).  This is because without, in this case, the second 3, there is less than 90% of the data, which is possibly worse than having >90% of the data.  How to do this is beyond my PYTHON programming skills.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you, you actually keep only 80% of your data in your example. Do you want to remove samples at random from each of the three categories, or should that be weighted (i.e. each sample has an equal chance of being removed)? Is 90% supposed to be hard limit or an average?

Comment: No, just a typo. fixed now
Hard limit would be preferred

Comment: what about the second sample?

Comment: Oh, just saw that I only answered one question.  I only want to remove either those columns, dog, cat, or tarsier from each sample.  Each of these has an equal chance, just as long as 90% of the data remains

Comment: Ok, now I realize that I have created a gap in the logic as in reference to the above comments concerning the 2nd sample, which value would be thrown away (both are 3)?  Ideally, I would have a sorted list or dictionary, and if the percent cutoff came to this point, I would take the first one randomly and remove the rest.  That is, unless someone can think of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm right you removed "dog" because it was <=10% of the total number of animal.
let's create a struct

```
struct row{
    char *name;
    int animal[3]; //id 0 is dog, 1 is cat and 2 is tarsier
}
```

then every time you put the read data into this struct, you can simply set to 0 every field <=10%:

```
int i;
float sum=0; //we need float to force the result to be float
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
    sum += row.animal[i]; //count the total row population
}
for (i=0;i<3;i++){ //for every animal
    if (row.animal[i]/sum <= 0.1){ //if this animal is equal or less than 10% of the row population
        row.animal[i]=0; //set his population to 0
    }
}
```

as you can read, because of the animal array with this code you can have an arbitrary (but fixed) number of animal.

Comment: whops, was late and i was cross posting to C section :) but the logic remain the same

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Python 3 (it might work in Py2 also but I don't know), just treat it as a CSV delimited by tabs's instead of commas--

```
import csv

def getvals(file):
    """
        gets the val's from a file of whitespace separated values, and 
        turns them into easy to use Python var's
    """
    samples = csv.reader(open(file))
    s = []
    n = 0
    for row in samples:
        r = [row[0].split()]
        s += r
        n+=1
    return s
```

That function, would return a set that looks like this --

```
[
 ['Sample', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Tarsier'], 
 ['A47', '1', '7', '2'], 
 ['A48', '3', '3', '4'], 
 ['A51', '2', '1', '8'], 
 ['A53', '0', '0', '0'], 
 ['A54', '1', '7', '2'], 
 ['A57', '0', '0', '10']
]
```

From there, it's just a matter of some math to determine which value to throw away. of course, you could just do the math in the for loop and return the values you want too. I just like to return sets of values that can be played with by many other functions, so I did it like that.

Comment: Yeah I usually start my programs similarly.  But although I can do this in excel or, like you say with some simple math, incorporating this into python is the reason why I asked the question.  Not necessarily how to start it.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question. Is this about how to do it in Python? Or is it about how to do the math?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you to consider [NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org).

With NumPy, you can define what is called a structured array, an array where each row is composed of different fields you can name and access directly.

Supposing your data is stored in a tab-delimited file `data.dat`, using the format you describe, you would do

```
>>> data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter="\t", names=True, dtype=None)
```

The [`np.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html) function reads your data from `'data.txt'`, splitting each line along `delimiter`, using the first line to get the names of your fields (`names=True`), and guessing what is the type of data for each field (`data=None`). With your example, I get

```
data = array([('A47', 1, 7, 2), ('A48', 3, 3, 4), ('A51', 2, 1, 8),
       ('A53', 0, 0, 0), ('A54', 1, 7, 2), ('A57', 0, 0, 10)], 
      dtype=[('Sample', '|S3'), ('Dog', '<i8'), ('Cat', '<i8'), ('Tarsier', '<i8')])
```

From here, we can choose a combination of fields

```
>>> data[["Cat","Tarsier"]]
array([(7, 2), (3, 4), (1, 8), (0, 0), (7, 2), (0, 10)], 
  dtype=[('Cat', '<i8'), ('Tarsier', '<i8')])
```

or only a few rows:

```
>>> data[[0,2]]
array([('A47', 1, 7, 2), ('A51', 2, 1, 8)], 
     dtype=[('Sample', '|S3'), ('Dog', '<i8'), ('Cat', '<i8'), ('Tarsier', '<i8')])
```

do some statistics on a field:

```
>>> data["Dog"].mean()
1.1666667
```

in short, you can filter your data the way you want.